# see my desktop on two monitors Lubuntu

Tags: 11.10, video, monitor, lubuntu

Ok I have an ascer aspire with a AMD Radeon HD 6320, when I try to connect a CRT monitor in to it I can see the same desktop in the 2 monitors.

[image: The monitor manager]

I want to see in the 2 monitors se same desktop as a continue no 2 identic desktops.

I want to extend my desktop to monitor 2

Can some body tell me how to do this?.

Comment: You mean that you want to extend your desktop to monitor 2?

Comment: that's right maybe I not so clear in the question.. I will add that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a good explanation of how to configure these settings:  http://a19.video2.blip.tv/10540008615475/Llelectronics-LubuntuScreencastMultimonitoring462.webm?brs=789&bri=8.6

What you likely want is arandr (sudo apt-get install arandr) -- > access it through: preferences --> Arandr

The GUI is pretty intuitive.

If you have an NVIDIA driver then the solution is slightly different. Its explained in the (excellent) screen-cast.

Comment: this works great! but have an issue: created a new question here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/125370/help-with-arandr-setup

Comment: Here's a prime example of why "outbound link answers" are not very good. "The requested URL /10540008615475/Llelectronics-LubuntuScreencastMultimonitoring462.webm was not found on this server." Even more frustrating as I need this and the two comments above stated it was ideal. Please, copy/paste external info, then state as such, and include source link.

Comment: @jJames Its a bit tough to paste the info if the link is to a screencast. Try arandr and post back if you have problems using it. As mentioned its pretty intuitive. This should help you: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ub7pn-PUKjA. Its a similar (possibly the same) screen cast by the same people. Arandr is just a GUI of xrandr, which is what the screencast deals with. arandr content starts at about 8 mins. If you want to write out the screencast, please do.

Answer (score 2):

I was reading [this](http://willem.engen.nl/projects/disper/); it's an app that can help you extend your desktop.

You can add the PPA repo: execute these commands one by one:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:disper-dev/ppa
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nmellegard/disper-indicator-ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install disper disper-indicator
```

[Read more here....](http://www.joeyconway.com/blog/2011/08/13/ubuntu-how-to-extend-display-with-two-monitors/)

Comment: ok I tryed out what you show me here, disper-indicator doesn't work veery well but now when I do all the "normal" set up now it works

Comment: I'm glad that at least yo got what you wanted.