# monitors are duplicated after update

Tags: multiple-monitors, monitor

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 using a dual monitor setup.

Every once in a while I update my system via `apt-get update` followed by `apt-get upgrade`.

After reboot the first monitor is duplicated to the second one. When I go to `System settings -> Display and monitor` and I click on the info button both displays show the same input source (HDMI),  which is obviously wrong.

Any ideas on how to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The actual name should be `Screen Display` and not `Display and monitor` as this shows:

[image: Screen Display]

In the middle of the window uncheck the option that says ***Mirror Displays***.

It has happened to me before where extended displays mysteriously changed to mirrored. However it's been a long time since this has happened and it's only ocurred once or twice since upgrading to **16.04** in August 2016.

Comment: Hi, thx for your input. I didn't specify that I'm running KDE 5.5.5 and for some reason this option is not available to me

Comment: answered my own question. thx for your help though!

Comment: Actually I suspected you weren't running Unity because it was called "Display and monitor" and you have "HDMI" option which doesn't appear on my screen.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it with the help of this answer:
https://askubuntu.com/a/91250

I just executed the xrandr commands for my specific setting and it seems to work again.